# how to copy a list files in to certain directories?

Tags: batch-file

Consider i am having a file input.txt which contains file list
**input.txt** 
img001.img,
doc001.docx,
doc002.docx,
csv001.csv,
pdf001.pdf,
csv002.csv

```
@echo off 
del /f Dirfilelisttemp.txt 
rd DirTempList 

echo            *****       READ Started,Input.txt      *****
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do ( 
      dir /s /b D:\com\example_4.1\%%a>>Dirfilelisttemp.txt 
    )
echo            *****       READ COMPLETED Input.txt        *****

echo            *****       Render Started,Dirfilelisttemp.txt      *****
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Dirfilelisttemp.txt) do ( 
      xcopy /e /v /s %%a" /-y  D:\DirTempFolder 
    )       
echo            *****Render COMPLETED,Dirfilelisttemp.txt       *****
```

**Note: Dirfilelisttemp.txt**  
D:\com\example_4.1\img\img001.img,
D:\com\example_4.1\docs\doc001.docx,
D:\com\example_4.1\docs\doc002.docx,
D:\com\example_4.1\csv\csv001.csv,
D:\com\example_4.1\csv\csv002.csv
D:\com\example_4.1\csv\pdf001.pdf

**Desired output:** 
D:\DirTempFolder\com\example_4.1\img\img001.img,
D:\DirTempFolder\com\example_4.1\docs\doc001.docx,
D:\DirTempFolder\com\example_4.1\docs\doc002.docx,
D:\DirTempFolder\com\example_4.1\csv\csv001.csv,
D:\DirTempFolder\com\example_4.1\csv\csv002.csv
D:\DirTempFolder\com\example_4.1\csv\pdf001.pdf

**Actual Output:** 
D:\DirTempFolder\img001.img,
D:\DirTempFolder\doc001.docx,
D:\DirTempFolder\doc002.docx,
D:\DirTempFolder\csv001.csv,
D:\DirTempFolder\pdf001.pdf,
D:\DirTempFolder\csv002.csv

After executing this, i am getting "actual output". But i couldn't able to get desired output.
is their any solution for getting desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a few simple changes to your last for loop and add delayedexpansion

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist Dirfilelisttemp del /f /q Dirfilelisttemp.txt 
if exist DirTempList rd /s /q DirTempList 

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do ( 
  dir /s /b "D:\com\example_4.1\%%a">>Dirfilelisttemp.txt 
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Dirfilelisttemp.txt) do ( 
  set "ext=%%~xa" & set ext=!ext:,=!
  if not exist "c:\Temp%%~pa" md "c:\Temp%%~pa"
  xcopy /e /v /s "%%~dpna!ext!" /-y  "D:\DirTempFolder%%~pa"
)
```

You didn't specify to remove the commas at the end of the filename but I doubt you have them in your extension so I removed them.

Comment: i am getting "Parser Error" after executing that D:\DirTempFolder%%~pa

Comment: it parses out just the path from the full file path. At the very end of help for `for` it lists them. Type `For /?` at the command line to see the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "sourceDir=D:\com\example_4.1"
    set "targetDir=D:\DirTempFolder"

    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("input.txt"
    ) do for %%b in ("%sourceDir%\%%~a"
    ) do if exist "%%~fb" xcopy /y "%%~fb" "%targetDir%%%~pb"

    endlocal
```